# Spring-Boot Configuration for suppressing BatchDataInitializer

Tags: spring-batch, spring-boot

I am using Spring-boot 0.5.0.M6 with Spring-Batch. Configuration has by using @EnableBatchProcessing with datasource etc configured in application.properties.

During first run of the application, everything works fine but after I stop the application and restart application, following error is seen

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:239)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:659)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:908)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:969)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:974)
```

When digging down, i had observed following lines in logs

```
2013-12-06 12:12:37 INFO  ResourceDatabasePopulator:162 - Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql]
2013-12-06 12:12:37 INFO  ResourceDatabasePopulator:217 - Done executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql] in 13 ms.
```

Root problem over here was schema-drop-mysql.sql was not triggered by schema-mysql.sql was triggered, thereby creating two entries in BATCH_JOB_SEQ.

For resolution of the same, I have added

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={BatchAutoConfiguration.class})
```

However due to this I need to execute schema-mysql.sql explicitly, which as of now is ok, but would be problem when spring-batch version would be updated with updates in schema

Hence have couple of questions:
1. How to autoconfigure batch for even executing schema-drop-mysql.sql  before schema-mysql.sql?
2. is there way to configure this BatchDatabaseInitializer to run kind of "update" mode?

Regards

Comment: Isn't that just a DEBUG log? Is it harmful?

Comment: Yes Dave, it is DEBUG log. But the problem is in debug log, I can not see schema-drop-mysql.sql getting executed. Hence what happens over here is BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ, BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ and BATCH_JOB_SEQ adds additional rows with value as 0. Spring batch then tries to restart the job sequence from 0 rather than earlier sequence. This results in org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException.

Comment: Right, I see. Michael and I discussed this a while ago and he said he'd modify the schema. Maybe we need to update the Spring Batch version? Or maybe add an option to drop, as you suggest. A [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot) would be a good place to discuss.

Comment: Thanks Dave and Michael. As suggested, raised issue in GitHub issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/149 for the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the current version of Spring Batch autoconfiguration that isn't possible with the upcoming version it is possible to disable the automatic creation of the database tables by specifying the `spring.batch.initializer.enabled` property and setting it to `false`.

IMHO you shouldn't use the automatic creation/update features to create schema's either do  it yourself or use tools like [LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org) or [FlyWay](http://flywaydb.org/) to do it more controlled.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418814/db-migration-tool-liquibase-or-flyway

You can always execute the `schema-drop-mysql.sql` yourself, as a work around you could add a `@PreDestroy` method to your `@Configuration` class which executes this script. (Maybe you could even add this to an `@Configuration` class which is enabled only in dev mode/profile).

Comment: Hi. I agree with usage of tool similar to FlyWay for custom schema/entities. However these tables are integrated with Spring batch framework. Hence I would like to rely on sqls bundled in spring batch framework. This would ease up migrating to next verion of spring batch. Regarding preDestroy method, again similar issue. these SQLs are bundled inside the JAR. Hence for providing path, explicit version of the spring batch jar needs to be detailed out application.

Comment: I nowhere said you shouldn't rely on the sqls provided. I merely stated that you shouldn't use the auto create features of the framework! The sql is in a (kind of) well known location so you can simply access it (with a `ClassPathResource` ). Also migration isn't supported only initial creation (at the moment), migration basically means drop everything and recreate. Which also means you loose the history of all executions.

Comment: Marking as resolved with latest comment on github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/149